# cant boot to windows after installing ubuntu 15.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

okzz this is what happened.. i was earlier using windows 8.1 with dual boot Ubuntu 14.04, updated it to 15.04.. there was some bug after i updated it (desktop went all black after i updated it, although not relevant...) so i downloaded 15.04 iso made a bootable pen drive and reinstalled Ubuntu 15.04. this is when things got messed up... now my laptop boots directly to Ubuntu. although i can access my windows partition from the Ubuntu... it just doesn't boots to the windows. i already have tried that boot-repair.. it still not showing windows although after that it started showing that purple screen where i can choose what to do...  help.

p.s. i dont have any windows cd or a recovery pendrive

Comment: try `sudo update-grub` in ubuntu terminal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Answer (score 3):

Install [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/grub-customizer), it lets you configure what options do you see in the 'purple screen'.

You can install it via the Terminal by:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Answer (score 1):

if `sudo update-grub` does not work, the thing might be Grub being configured to autostart Ubuntu. You can change that inside Grub Customizer, second panel.